# Exception creating empty C++ project with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, exception, project, visual-studio-2022

I need to create a C++ project with Visual Studio 2022 17.6.2 but while creating the project it crashes and shows a "Exception of type 'System.Exception'" was thrown" alert.
It seems to be related to every C++ project template offered by VS: I tried with Empty Project, Console App and CLR Empty Project (.NET) and the error is always the same.

If I run VS with /Log argument I can see these 3 errors in the log file:

```
780 
ERROR   System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown. at   Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.Solutions.Interop.IVsNativeEnvironmentInternal.WizLoadAndRunFile(String pwszWizard, String pwszDestination, Boolean bCloseSolution, Boolean bRunSilent, Array psaCustomParams, String pwszFrameworkVersion)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.Solutions.Dte.DteSolution.<AddFromTemplateExAsync>d__256.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.Solutions.Dte.DteSolution.<AddFromTemplateExAsync>d__256.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.CompleteOnCurrentThread()
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask`1.CompleteOnCurrentThread()
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.Solutions.Dte.DteSolution.AddFromTemplateEx(String FileName, String Destination, String ProjectName, String SolutionName, Boolean Exclusive, UInt32 Options)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.Solutions.Dte.DteSolution.<>c__DisplayClass25_0.<EnvDTE100.Solution4.AddFromTemplateEx>b__0()
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.NewProjectDialog.LegacyVsTemplateProvider.GetInstantiationResult(CreateProjectResult result)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.NewProjectDialog.LegacyProjectTemplateProvider.<InstantiateTemplateAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateProviders.TemplateProviderSupport.ExceptionLoggingTemplateProviderDecorator.<InstantiateTemplateAsync>d__9.MoveNext()          
Template provider aggregator    
2023/05/30 15:57:07.067

781 
ERROR   
Unable to load solution user option 'SccProvider.Solution.LoadCount'            SccDisplayInformation.SolutionOptions   
2023/05/30 15:57:07.115

782 
ERROR   
Unable to load solution user option 'SccProvider.Solution.LastBranch'           SccDisplayInformation.SolutionOptions   
2023/05/30 15:57:07.116
```

The issue happens to me also with VS2019.

Tried repairing/reinstalling VS2022 and reinstalling SDKs and other VS components via Visual Studio Installer.

Tried cleaning %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17._xxxx\ComponentModelCache.

Any other ideas to debug/fix it?

Thanks

Comment: There are settings that are stored in your user profile for Visual Studio.

Comment: You probably want to ask this on the Microsoft Forums.

Comment: I would try Tools-> Import and export settings -> Export to save your current settings somewhere if you want to, then Reset all settings in the same dialog.

Comment: SCC is about version control (source code control). Are you trying to create a new project with source control? Try without. Maybe your Git configuration is invalid or similar.

Comment: Tried resetting user settings but still not solved. I'm creating an emtpy project without source control (anyway the SCC errors are throws also on my colleagues' machines, and they still can create a C++ project. I think it may not be related.)

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

I fixed the `Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown` alert by doing full cleanup and reinstall and removing `VCTargetsPath` from the windows system environment variables

## Additional info

I found [this comment](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/SystemException-when-I-try-to-create-a/10201751#T-N10202780) which recommends to do these steps:

> - See if you have this file on your machine: `%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\InstallCleanup.exe`
> - Start an admin command prompt
>
>   - Right-click on cmd.exe and select Run AsAdministrator
> - If so, please launch it from an admin command prompt with a -full param
>
>   - InstallCleanup.exe -full
> - If not, please manually delete the `%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer` folder
> - Verify that your initial install location for VS is removed. If it is not, delete it manually.
> - Relaunch the newly downloaded (https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/)
> - Allow the first step to install the installer
> - Once the installer comes up and you can see workload choices (.net desktop and the like), close it
> - Go launch the same InstallCleanup.exe to clean up old build of VS
> - Then relaunch vs_enterprise.exe and install VS.

So I did the following:

1. I executed the mentioned cleanup routine by running cmd as admin and performing `InstallCleanup.exe -full`
2. I removed installation folders

   - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio`
   - `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio`
3. I removed folder `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio`
4. Removed `VCTargetsPath` from the Windows System Environment variables list
5. Then I installed the visual studio via the installer with workloads (I don't think one needs all of them but for completeness I'm listing what I did):

   - ASP.NET and web development
   - .NET desktop development
   - Desktop development with C++
   - Universal Windows Platform development
   - Visual Studio extension development
   - Office/SharePoint development